# Random row from Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

What is the best (and fastest) way to retrieve a random row using Linq to SQL when I have a condition, e.g. some field must be true?

Comment: You have two options for the order you check the true conditions. If the true condition happens on most items then just grab a random item then test and repeat while false. If rare let the database limit the options to the true condition and then grab one at random.

Comment: As with lots of answers on this site - second-rated is much better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can do this at the database, by using a fake UDF; in a partial class, add a method to the data context:

```
partial class MyDataContext {
     [Function(Name="NEWID", IsComposable=true)] 
     public Guid Random() 
     { // to prove not used by our C# code... 
         throw new NotImplementedException(); 
     }
}
```

Then just `order by ctx.Random()`; this will do a random ordering at the SQL-Server courtesy of `NEWID()`. i.e.

```
var cust = (from row in ctx.Customers
           where row.IsActive // your filter
           orderby ctx.Random()
           select row).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this is only suitable for small-to-mid-size tables; for huge tables, it will have a performance impact at the server, and it will be more efficient to find the number of rows (`Count`), then pick one at random (`Skip/First`).

---

for count approach:

```
var qry = from row in ctx.Customers
          where row.IsActive
          select row;

int count = qry.Count(); // 1st round-trip
int index = new Random().Next(count);

Customer cust = qry.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault(); // 2nd round-trip
```

Comment: My table has approximately 30.000 rows, would you say it's small-to-mid size?

Comment: If is it 30k *after* the filter, I'd say no: don't use this approach. Do 2 round-trips; 1 to get the Count(), and 1 to get a random row...

Comment: +1 This is a much better approach than what I had said.  I nominated mine for deletion.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your comment, il use the 2 round-trip version.

Comment: What if you want five (or "x") random rows?  Is it best just to make six round-trips or is there a convenient way to implement it in a stored procedure?

Comment: @Neal S.: the order by ctx.Random() could be mixed with Take(5); but if you are using the Count() approach, I expect 6 round trips is the simplest option.

Comment: don't forget to add a reference to System.Data.Linq or the System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Function attribute wont work.

Comment: [sighs happily] Marc Gravell does it again!  What would we do without him?  THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @Shaul probably have better up-time on stackoverflow :p

Comment: I know this is old, but if you are selecting many random rows from a large table, see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx    I don't know if there's a LINQ equivalent.

Comment: @MarcGravell i am trying the 2nd option cause the table has many records, but some records are missing when returned, eg: when `
**first request** count 4
index 1

shows 3 product in view


**second request** count 4
index 2 

shows 2 product in view

**third request** count 4
index 3

shows 1 product in view` may i know what i am missing ?

Answer (score 63):

Another sample for Entity Framework:

```
var customers = db.Customers
                  .Where(c => c.IsActive)
                  .OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid())
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

This does not work with LINQ to SQL. The `OrderBy` is simply being dropped.

Comment: Have you profiled this and confirmed that it works? In my tests using LINQPad, the order by clause is being dropped.

Comment: This is the best solution to this problem

Comment: This doesn't workin LINQ to SQL... maybe it works in Entity Framework 4 (not confirming it). You can only use .OrderBy with Guid if you are sorting a List... with DB it won't work.

Comment: Just to finally confirm that this works in EF4 - it's great option in that case.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain why the orderBy with a new Guid  do the trick? Nice answer by the way :)

Answer (score 35):

EDIT: I've only just noticed this is LINQ to SQL, not LINQ to Objects. Use Marc's code to get the database to do this for you. I've left this answer here as a potential point of interest for LINQ to Objects.

Strangely enough, you don't actually need to get the count. You do, however, need to fetch every element unless you get the count.

What you can do is keep the idea of a "current" value and the current count. When you fetch the next value, take a random number and replace the "current" with "new" with a probability of 1/n where n is the count.

So when you read the first value, you *always* make that the "current" value. When you read the second value, you *might* make that the current value (probability 1/2). When you read the third value, you *might* make that the current value (probability 1/3) etc. When you've run out of data, the current value is a random one out of all the ones you read, with uniform probability.

To apply that with a condition, just ignore anything which doesn't meet the condition. The easiest way to do that is to only consider the "matching" sequence to start with, by applying a Where clause first.

Here's a quick implementation. I *think* it's okay...

```
public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                 Random rng)
{
    T current = default(T);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        count++;
        if (rng.Next(count) == 0)
        {
            current = element;
        }            
    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: FYI - I ran a quick check and this function does have a uniform probability distribution (the incrementing count is essentially the same mechanism as the Fisher-Yates shuffle so it seems reasonable that it should be).

Comment: @Greg: Cool, thanks. It looked okay to me with a quick check, but it's so easy to get off-by-one errors in code like this. Virtually irrelevant to LINQ to SQL of course, but useful nonetheless.

Comment: @JonSkeet, hi, can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30752514/2218697) and let me know what i am missing

Comment: @TylerLaing: No, there's not meant to be a break. On the first iteration, `current` will *always* be set to the first element. On the second iteration, there's a 50% change that it will be set to the second element. On the third iteration, there's a 33% chance it will be set to the third element. Adding a break statement would mean you'd always exit after reading the first element, making it not random at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Doh! I misread your use of count (e.g. was thinking this was Fisher-Yates style with a random range like n-i).  But to select the first element in Fisher-Yates is to fairly choose any of the elements.  However, that requires knowing the total number of elements.  I see now that your solution is neat for an IEnumerable in that the total count is not known, and there is no need to iterate over the whole source just to get the count, to then iterate again to some randomly chosen index. Rather this solves in one pass, as you stated: "need to fetch every element unless you get the count".

Comment: Shorthand: `public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng) => source.Where((x, i) => rng.Next(i + 1) == 0).Last();`

Answer (score 21):

One way to achieve efficiently is to add a column to your data `Shuffle` that is populated with a random int (as each record is created).

The partial query to access the table in random order is ...

```
Random random = new Random();
int seed = random.Next();
result = result.OrderBy(s => (~(s.Shuffle & seed)) & (s.Shuffle | seed)); // ^ seed);
```

This does an XOR operation in the database and orders by the results of that XOR.

Advantages:-

1. Efficient: SQL handles the
   ordering, no need to fetch the whole
   table
2. Repeatable: (good for
   testing) - can use the same random
   seed to generate the same random
   order

This is the approach used by my home automation system to randomize playlists.  It picks a new seed each day giving a consistent order during the day (allowing easy pause / resume capabilities) but a fresh look at each playlist each new day.

Comment: what would the effect on randomness be if instead of adding a random int field you just used an existing auto-incrementing identity field (the seed would obviously remain random)?  also - is a seed value with a a maximum equal to the number of records in the table adequate or should it be higher?

Comment: Agreed, this is a great answer which IMO should have more upvotes. I used this in an Entity Framework query, and the bitwise-XOR operator ^ seems to work directly thus making the condition a bit cleaner: `result = result.OrderBy(s => s.Shuffle ^ seed);` (ie. no need to implement the XOR via the ~, & and | operators).

Answer (score 8):

if you want to get e.g. `var count = 16` random rows from table, you can write

```
var rows = Table.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
                        .Take(count);
```

here I used E.F, and the Table is a Dbset

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of getting random rows is sampling, I have talked very briefly [here](http://qualityofdata.com/2011/02/13/sampling-data-with-sql-server/) about a nice approach from Larson et al., Microsoft Research team where they have developed a sampling framework for Sql Server using materialized views. There is a link to the actual paper also.

Answer (score 0):

I have random function query against `DataTable`s:

```
var result = (from result in dt.AsEnumerable()
              order by Guid.NewGuid()
              select result).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here wondering how to get a few random pages from a small number of them, so each user gets some different random 3 pages.

This is my final solution, working querying with LINQ against a list of pages in Sharepoint 2010. It's in Visual Basic, sorry :p

```
Dim Aleatorio As New Random()

Dim Paginas = From a As SPListItem In Sitio.RootWeb.Lists("Páginas") Order By Aleatorio.Next Take 3
```

Probably should get some profiling before querying a great number of results, but it's perfect for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to SQL in LINQPad as C# statements look like

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = this.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(@"SELECT top 10 * from [Customers] order by newid()");
customers.Dump();
```

The generated SQL is

```
SELECT top 10 * from [Customers] order by newid()
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below will call the source to retrieve a count and then apply a skip expression on the source with a number between 0 and n. The second method will apply order by using the random object (which will order everything in memory) and select the number passed into the method call.

```
public static class IEnumerable
{
    static Random rng = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        T current = default(T);
        int c = source.Count();
        int r = rng.Next(c);
        current = source.Skip(r).First();
        return current;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> RandomElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int number)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(r => rng.Next()).Take(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Comment: This code is not threadsafe and can only be used in single threaded code (so **not** ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

i use this method for take random news and its work fine ;)

```
    public string LoadRandomNews(int maxNews)
    {
        string temp = "";

        using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var newsCount = (from p in db.Tbl_DynamicContents
                             where p.TimeFoPublish.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now
                             select p).Count();
            int i;
            if (newsCount < maxNews)
                i = newsCount;
            else i = maxNews;
            var r = new Random();
            var lastNumber = new List<int>();
            for (; i > 0; i--)
            {
                int currentNumber = r.Next(0, newsCount);
                if (!lastNumber.Contains(currentNumber))
                { lastNumber.Add(currentNumber); }
                else
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        currentNumber = r.Next(0, newsCount);
                        if (!lastNumber.Contains(currentNumber))
                        {
                            lastNumber.Add(currentNumber);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currentNumber == newsCount)
                    currentNumber--;
                var news = (from p in db.Tbl_DynamicContents
                            orderby p.ID descending
                            where p.TimeFoPublish.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now
                            select p).Skip(currentNumber).Take(1).Single();
                temp +=
                    string.Format("<div class=\"divRandomNews\"><img src=\"files/1364193007_news.png\" class=\"randomNewsImg\" />" +
                                  "<a class=\"randomNews\" href=\"News.aspx?id={0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a></div>",
                                  news.ID, news.Title);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **LINQPad**, switch to **C# program** mode and do this way:

```
void Main()
{
    YourTable.OrderBy(v => Random()).FirstOrDefault.Dump();
}

[Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)]
public Guid Random()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cust = (from c in ctx.CUSTOMERs.ToList() select c).OrderBy(x => x.Guid.NewGuid()).Taket(2);
```

Select random 2 row

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marc Gravell's solution. If you are not working with the datacontext class itself (because you proxy it somehow e.g. to fake the datacontext for testing purposes), you cannot use the defined UDF directly: it will not be compiled to SQL because you're not using it in a subclass or partial class of your real data context class.

A workaround for this problem is to create a Randomize function in your proxy, feeding it with the query you want to be randomized:

```
public class DataContextProxy : IDataContext
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public DataContextProxy(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // Snipped irrelevant code

    public IOrderedQueryable<T> Randomize<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.OrderBy(x => _context.Random());
    }
}
```

Here is how you'd use it in your code:

```
var query = _dc.Repository<SomeEntity>();
query = _dc.Randomize(query);
```

To be complete, this is how to implement this in the FAKE datacontext (which uses in memory entities):

```
public IOrderedQueryable<T> Randomize<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```