# Selecting random elements in a list conditional on attribute

Tags: python, list, random

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

#initialize values
state_0_agents = 10
state_1_agents = 10
numberofselections = 2 #number of agents who can choose to transition to the higher plane

#list of agents
agents = [Agent(0) for i in range(state_0_agents)]
agents.extend(Agent(1) for i in range(state_1_agents))

random.choice(agents)
```

I want to randomly select a couple of agents from this Agents list whose state I will end up changing to 1. Unfortunately the `random.choice` function selects among all the elements. However I want to randomly select only *among* those whose state is 0.

I would prefer if this could occur without creating a new list.

Comment: I think your choices are to make a new list and then choose from that, or repeatedly choose randomly until the one you choose has state==0.

Comment: You'll either have to create a new list, or keep retrying the `random.choice()` call until it returns one with `.state` set to `0`.

Comment: If I keep retrying random choice then its possible nothing will happen for a bunch of periods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see 3 options here:

- Create a list anyway, you can do so with a list comprehension:

  ```
  random.choice([a for a in agents if a.state == 0])
  ```
- Put the `random.choice()` call in a loop, keep trying until you get one that matches the criteria:

  ```
  while True:
      agent = random.choice(agents)
      if agent.state == 0:
          break
  ```
- Index your `agents` list, then pick from that index; these are really just lists still:

  ```
  agent_states_index = {}
  for index, agent in enumerate(agents):
      agent_states_index.setdefault(agent.state, []).append(index)

  agent_index = random.choice(agent_states_index[0])
  agent = agents[agent_index]
  ```

Comment: Great! Thanks! That fake list gives me a bit of a headache but it works!

Answer (score 5):

There are four algorithms I know of for this.

The first is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966108/choose-random-array-element-satisfying-certain-property).  Iterate through the array, then if  you come across an element that satisfies a condition, check to see if a random integer is less than `(1/(however many elements you've passed that satisfy the condition))`.

The second is to iterate through your array, adding to a new array elements that fulfill the condition, then randomly pick one out of that list.

Both of these algorithms run in O(n) time, where n is the size of the array.  They are guaranteed to find an element if it is there and satisfies the condition.

There are another two algorithms that are much faster.  They both run in O(1) time but have some major weaknesses.

The first is to keep picking indexes randomly until you hit on one that satisfies the condition.  This has a potentially infinite time complexity but is O(1) in practice.  (If there are very few elements that satisfy the condition and the array is very large, something like 1 in 10000 elements, this becomes slower.)  It is also not guaranteed to find an element if it is not there; if there is no element that satisfies the condition, you either have an infinite loop or have to write the algorithm to make a finite number  of guesses and you might miss an element even if it is there.

The second is to pick a random index, then keep incrementing it until you find an index that satisfies the condition.  It is guaranteed to either find an acceptable index or look through all of the indexes without entering into an infinite loop. It has the downside of not being completely random.  Obviously, if you increment the index by 1 every time, it will be *really, really* nonrandom (if there are clumps of acceptable indexes in the array).  However, if you choose the increment randomly from one of a handful of numbers that are coprime to the number of elements of the array, then it's still not fair and random, but is fairly fair and random, and guaranteed to succeed.

Again, these last 2 algorithms are very fast but are either not guaranteed to work or not guaranteed to be completely random.  I don't know of an algorithm that is both fast, guaranteed to work, and completely fair and random.

Comment: I should probably specify that, if you have the memory, the best way to do it is probably to create a new list (like in Martijn's response) or use a numpy array made from the old list (like Antonvh's response), but the original post said not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy.where:

```
import numpy as np

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

#initialize values
state_0_agents = 10
state_1_agents = 10

#list of agents
agents = [0]*state_0_agents
agents += [1]*state_1_agents

selected_agent_idx = random.choice(np.where(np.array(agents) == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `nonzero` function in numpy as it returns a list of indices where an iterable is not zero. Then you can combine it with the `choice` function to change the value of a random in a element index of that list:

```python
import numpy as np
index_agent0 = np.nonzero(agents==0)[0]
agents[np.random.choice(index_agent0)] = 1
```