# Random LINQ to SQL records w/ "int" primary keys

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

How do I get a 5 random records from a LINQ to SQL Table[T]?

All the examples I've found via google use uniqueidentifier as the primary key

http://www.davidmuto.com/Blog.muto/View/random-records-with-linq-to-sql

Is there a way to do this when the primary key is an auto-incrementing integer?

Some records can be deleted too, so the min to max ID set will have holes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you could take a look at this post which appears to have a way to do what you are seeking: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/10/randomizing-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx

> Let's detail the solution that uses a
>   SQL user-defined function. The most
>   common way to sort records randomly is
>   to use the NEWID SQL Server function.
>   This is what this solution uses.
>
> First, create the following view:
>
> CREATE VIEW RandomView AS SELECT
>   NEWID() As ID Then create the
>   following function that uses the view:
>
> CREATE FUNCTION GetNewId ( ) RETURNS
>   uniqueidentifier AS BEGIN RETURN
>   (SELECT ID FROM RandomView) END
>
> The view is required because it's not
>   possible to directly use NEWID in a
>   scalar function.
>
> You can then map the GetNewId
>   user-defined function using LINQ to
>   SQL's Function attribute. Again, see
>   chapter 8 for the details.
>
> That's it! You can now write LINQ
>   queries as usual. Here is an example
>   to pick a random object:
>
> var tool = db.Tools.OrderBy(t =>
>   db.GetNewId()).First()
>
> Here is another example that uses
>   GetNewId to sort results randomly:
>
> var tools =   from tool in db.Tools
>   orderby db.GetNewId()   select
>   tool.Name;

There is also this post on SO: [Random row from Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)