# Can I randomize the sequence of items in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: observablecollection, observable

I have an ObservableCollection with objects. I want to randomize the order of the collection. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning items randomly from a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866533/returning-items-randomly-from-a-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an extension method to do that. You can add this class to you project to provide an extension method for collections. It's a simple shuffle.

```
public static class ShuffleExtension
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

To use, call `yourcollection.Shuffle()`.