# How can I get a randomized collection out of linq-to-sql model?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, random

What's the right syntax for this?

```
var words= from h in db.Words
                  orderby(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()) //error
                  select h;

var words= from h in db.Words
                  orderby((a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()) //error
                  select h;

var words= from h in db.Words
                  orderby(Guid.NewGuid()) //no error but doesn't sort
                  select h;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql

Comment: interesting but that solution gives me a "Method 'System.Guid Random()' has no supported translation to SQL." error in this case

Comment: In that case you've missed off the  `[Function(Name="NEWID", IsComposable=true)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't mind not having all of your code embedded in the LINQ query, you can try this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomWords = from h in db.Words
                     orderby rnd.Next()
                     select h;
```

Though if you need the Guid approach:

```
var words = from h in db.Words
            orderby Guid.NewGuid()
            select h;
```

Comment: The first version would work for LINQ-to-Objects, but not LINQ-to-SQL surely? I'd have to check with the second version, but I didn't *think* that worked...