# Select N Random Records with Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a static table with 20+ records, I would like to select N (N<20) from that table in random manner. What is the best way to do it in the code with LINQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random row from Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @Ahmad, no it's not a duplicate as I was to be selecting a constant number (lets say 5) records but they have to be random. So I want to sort the dataset in the random manner before I do .take(5)

Comment: the solution in my proposed duplicate would work. You would query the items, order by the random function, then `.Take(N)` at the end of it. Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
int randomSkip;
int randomTake;

randomSkip = GenerateSomeAppropriateRandomNumber();
randomTake = GenerateSomeAppropriateRandomNumber();

resultSet = iEnumerable.Skip(randomSkip).Take(randomTake);
```

Comment: no, I always want to select a fixed amount of records. But the records within that subset should be random.

Comment: With this solution, each item has not the same probability of being selected

Answer (score 109):

Here's the best way:

```
var randomUsers = users.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(15);
```

Comment: i know this was ages ago but  your answer worked perfectly for me i was lookinf for ages!! thabks

Comment: Is generating a GUID for each element sensible? What's the complexity this vs that of just picking a random selection?

Comment: Dave Hillier, I think the issue with just picking a "random selection" is having to solve the random element of it. There is a cost to generating the Guids and sorting on them, but it is otherwise a brilliantly clean and reliable bit of code for getting a random set back. (Being that the GUIDS will create a new random order every time the query is run.) If the recordset was large then it might make sense to create a bit of code that would randomly select N, unique records, at random, from the resultset.

Comment: Perfect answer, I must say.