# Get random and specific items from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

This is how it should go. Table will show six values total, out of that three must be specific ones, and other three random ones, they can't match of course. Meaning that,
if I create two separate instances of `Currencies` model (which is in question), and from one single out three specific ones I need, and use other instance for getting random three, I would have to exclude those 3 specifics from the second instance. Example.

```
//instance
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var currencies = db.Currencies.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(today));

//first get three separate
currency1 = currencies.Where(c => c.Sign.Equals("EUR"));
currency2 = currencies.Where(c => c.Sign.Equals("USD"));
currency3 = currencies.Where(c => c.Sign.Equals("AUD"));

//second get three randoms
var currencies = db.Currencies.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(today)).OrderBy(d => db.GetNewID()).Take(3);
```

Now, there should be a way (I think) to alter the currencies at 2nd get to use `.Except` but I'm not sure how to make an exception of three values. How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [order by random linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449452/order-by-random-linq)

Comment: It is... Strange I haven't found that question, I'll alter mine since there are some changes anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I've altered my question. Thanks for alerting.

Answer (score 2):

Source: [Getting random records from a table using LINQ to SQL](http://simon-holman.net/2010/04/getting-random-records-from-a-table-using-linq-to-sql/)

```
var currencies = db.Currencies.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(today))
                                          .OrderBy(q => db.GetNewId())
                                          .Take(6);
```

Reference:
[Is there a way to select random rows?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/62075dfb-dc41-4c3a-beaf-0c97ae416a2d)
[Select N Random Records with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474053/select-n-random-records-with-linq)
[linq: order by random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449452/order-by-random-linq)

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks, this helped. So I'll vote you up :) But if you can take a look at my altered question now. Thanks!