# Get random number of rows from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, random, guid

I am trying to get 5 random number of rows from a large table (over 1 million rows) with a fast method.

So far what I have tested with these SQL queries:

**Method 1**

```
Select top 5 customer_id, customer_name 
from Customer TABLESAMPLE(1000 rows) 
order by newid()
```

This method estimated I/O cost is `0.0127546` so this is very fast (index scan nonclustered)

**Method 2**

```
select top 5 customer_id, customer_name 
from Customer 
order by newid()
```

This method's sort estimated I/O cost is `117.21189` and index scan nonclustered estimated I/O cost is `2.8735`, so this is affecting performance

**Method 3**

```
select top 5 customer_id, customer_name 
from Customer 
order by rand(checksum(*))
```

This method's sort estimated I/O cost is `117.212` and index scan nonclustered estimated I/O cost is `213.149`, this query is slower than all because estimated subtree cost is `213.228` so it's very slow.

**UPDATE:**

**Method 4**

```
select top 5 customer_id, customer_name, product_id
from Customer 
Join Product on product_id = product_id
where (customer_active = 'TRUE')
order by checksum(newid())
```

This approach is better and very fast. All the benchmark testing is fine.

**QUESTION**

How can I convert **Method 4** to LINQ-to-SQL? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about improve the random query performance or convert the query to LINQ?

Comment: How random do you want the result to be?  `TABLESAMPLE` is not really random (unless your rows are so large that only one fits on a page).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes first I am looking to convert Method 1 to LINQ if not possible then I am looking for better approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Actually client just want to fill up the space so I just need 5 random rows to show without effecting the performance.

Comment: if you want fill up space then why dont show up just TOP 5?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well he want to show random records even very old records or each page refresh not the latest.

Comment: Well as gordon say, Method 1 isnt really random, so I would go for Method 2. And I woudlnt use LINQ for this. I rather create a function on db and then use EF to call that function to retrive the 5 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert **Method 2** into Linq To Entities just use the solution answered by `jitender` which look like this:

```
var randomCoustmers = context.Customers.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);
```

But for **Method 1** which is very fast following your benchmarking, you need to do the following C# code because Linq To Entities doesn't have a LINQ equivalent for this SQL statement `TABLESAMPLE(1000 rows)`.

```
var randomCoustmers = context.Customers.SqlQuery("Select TOP 5 customer_id, customer_name from Customer TABLESAMPLE(1000 rows) order by newid()").ToList();
```

You can move the SQL statements into a SQL View or Stored Procedure which will receive the number of customers to take.

**UPDATE**

For **Method 4** which seems to be very fast (always by following your benchmark), you can do the following Linq To Entities:

```
var randomCoustmers = context.Customers.OrderBy(c => SqlFunctions.Checksum(Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);
```

Entity Framework can translate into SQL all functions that are defined into [**SqlFunctions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. In those functions we have `Checksum` function which will do what you want.

If you want to join with other tables you can do it without difficulty with Linq To Entites so I just simplified my version by querying only the `Customers` `DbSets`.

Comment: I am gonna test it, meanwhile I have updated the question, can you please check. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much. Method 4 with SqlFunctions working like charm. Very smooth and no load on the server. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739419/5621827)'s the best way:

```
var randomCoustmers = Customers.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);
```

Comment: In this case is better use the option close with `duplicated question`

Comment: You convert **Method 2** not **Method 1** as expected by the OP.

Comment: Actually I am already using it, but cost of I/O is very high so it's effecting the performance. **Method 2** is the same. I am looking for better approach.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I was thinking in the same way but I don't have rights to mark it as duplicate :-)

Comment: @ArbazAbid Then you need to rewrite the question. So either you want help to convert the query to LINQ or improve performance.

Comment: Sorry jitender, forgot you need 3000 rep to unlock that privilege.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no problem bro

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have updated the question, please check. Thanks

Comment: Again you are asking two different question. Decide which one you want help with. If you already think Method 4 is the right one, then perfomance details are irrelevant to answer the question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ok sorry, my bad. I just now need to convert Method 4 to LINQ to SQL. Thanks

Comment: Then I suggest you create a new question and ask just that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have posted a new a question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852273/convert-sql-query-to-linq-to-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852273/convert-sql-query-to-linq-to-sql) Please check it, thanks