# Convert SQL Query to LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need help converting SQL query to LINQ to SQL

```
select top 5 customer_id, customer_name, product_id
from Customer 
Join Product on product_id = product_id
where (customer_active = 'TRUE')
order by checksum(newid())
```

How can I do that in LINQ to SQL. Thanks

Comment: It is a lil bit weird because => `product_id = product_id` will alwyas return true. Are you sure that your SQL works? Anyway can we have the entities class and your DbContext?

Comment: yeah this is just a example data, SQL is working fine like you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @CodeNotFound: Please check out below, This is how I did in my code (This is just an example). If you want me to mark this accepted answer, please add your and I will mark it. Thanks

Comment: Glad you find the solution. You're welcome. Thanks. Just accept your own answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved. Thanks to 'CodeNotFound' for this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43850748/1655774

```
db.Customer.Where(p => p.customer_active == true).Select(p => new CustomerViewModel
    {
         Customer_id= p.customer_id,
         Customer_name = p.customer_name,
         Product_id = p.Product.product_id
    }).OrderBy(c => SqlFunctions.Checksum(Guid.NewGuid())).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
( from p in  Customer  
         join q in Product  on p.product_id  equals q.product_id
         join q in Product  on p.product_id  equals q.product_id
         where customer_active ==true  select new 
         {
            customer_id=p.customer_id,
            customer_name=p.customer_name,
            product_id=q.product_id
        }).OrderBy(c => SqlFunctions.Checksum(Guid.NewGuid())).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this way to remove Boolean condition and reduce code

if you need to check bool condition in Ef

1.For True Condition
db.Customer.Where(p => p.customer_active).select(m=>m).tolist();
1.For False Condition
db.Customer.Where(p => !p.customer_active).select(m=>m).tolist();

just for suggestion