# System.Data.Function is not available in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm currently trying to create a NEWID() function in my DataContext in LINQ using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql/648247#648247), however, when adding the partial class to my DataContext.vb or a separate DataContextPartial.vb, I get the error `System.Data.Function is not available in this context because it is 'Friend'`.

I've come across this when accessing data types before and that was in easy fix of setting it to Public, but I'm not sure where the properties for `function` could be or how to change them.

The code I have is converted to VB.NET from the C# in the linked answer above:

```
Partial Public Class CMSModelDataContext
    <[Function](Name:="NEWID", IsComposable:=True)> _
    Public Function Random() As Guid
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember offhand whether VB applies the "Attribute" suffix automatically. Try this instead:

```
<FunctionAttribute(Name:="NEWID", IsComposable:=True)>
```

... and make sure you have an import for `System.Data.Linq.Mapping`.

EDIT: It looks like VB *does* apply the `Attribute` suffix, so I *suspect* you were missing an import or a reference. However, specifying `FunctionAttribute` explicitly will at least help you to verify this by removing the "false positive" of `System.Data.Function`.

Comment: VB .NET compiler does it, however this will uncover the fact that it went looking for `System.Data.Function` instead.

Comment: @gaearon: I was just editing my answer with pretty much exactly the same sentiment :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should

```
Import System.Data.Linq.Mapping
```

because [`FunctionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.functionattribute.aspx) resides there.

You didn't import the namespace, and compiler went to look for the class in the wrong direction. Trying its best and seeing that you have imported `System.Data`, compiler assumed you want to use `System.Data.Function` which is an internal (`Friend`) class in `System.Data.dll` assembly, hence the error.

One can wonder what exactly is the purpose of this error message. If the class isn't accessible anyway, why even bothering to tell about it? I think the reason is you could've referenced your own assembly forgetting to make some of types `Public`. It makes sense that compiler warns you that it *sees* the class but you just *can't use it*. It also makes sense applying same rules to all references, including framework libraries, although obviously you can't modify anything in there.

I would argue that `FunctionAttribute` is not a particularly good choice of name because it's begging for wrong namespace imports and related confusion.