# Entity Random Select from DB C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, random

Try to find the solution but i cant.

So problem is next one. I have the EDM model of database. I have a class with functions to get data from DB.
Like this:

```
public IQueryable<photos> FindUserPhotos(string userlogin)
        {
            return from m in db.photos
                   where m.userlogin == userlogin
                   select m;
        }
```

How to get the Random 10 lines from DB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random row from Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Random row from Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

```
public photos FindRandomUserPhoto(string userlogin)
{
   var qry = FindUserPhotos(userlogin);
   int count = qry.Count();
   int index = new Random().Next(count);
   return qry.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
}

public Array<photos> Find10RandomUserPhotos(string userlogin)
{
   var result = New Array<photos>;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      result.add(FindRandomUserPhoto(userlogin));
   }
   return result
}
```

Comment: If this is a dupe, don't post the link as an answer...post a comment instead.

Comment: dont know how to vote do close.. maybe dont have permission yet?

Comment: its not the dublicate, im a new in mvc and i realy dont understand how to make in by that example

Comment: updated.. maybe you can speed that up by using 10 skips with random based on count/10.

Answer (score 4):

I always use this method for get custom entity OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())

```
public photos Find10RandomUserPhotos(string userlogin)
{
   return db.photos.Where(x => x.userlogin == userlogin).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
}
```