# LINQ to SQL getting a random row from a database

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random row from Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

I want to get a random row from a table in database with linq to sql .how I can do that ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/10/randomizing-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx you could do this with additional view

Comment: Not really... see the "duplicate" mentioned above