# Efficiently select random rows from large resultset with LINQ (ala TABLESAMPLE)

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, random, linq-to-entities

I want to select a handful of random rows from the results of a complex query on a very large table (many millions of rows).

I am using SQL Server 2008, and the proper way to do this efficiently seems to be the [TABLESAMPLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx) clause.

Note 1: I am not interested in the popular "order by NEWID()" solution - it is inefficient for large tables.

Note 2: Since my query is complex, I do not want to have to first calculate the COUNT over it, if possible.

Note 3: Since the resultset is huge, I do not want to have to traverse it myself, such as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql/648240#648240).

The kicker is that I am using LINQ. Specifically, LINQ-To-Entities.

Is there a LINQ-friendly way to use TABLESAMPLE?

Even if there is no direct support, is there some way I can write most of my query in LINQ and then do a small amount of manual SQL to perform the TABLESAMPLE?

Comment: Be aware that TABLESAMPLE will not give you a truly random sample.

Comment: @Mitch - Point taken. The exact distribution doesn't matter to me in this case, as long as it's somewhat scattered.

Comment: +1. Interesting question. Perhaps change title to "Select random rows from a very large table using LINQ"

Comment: Good point; I updated the title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql Ah! I see you have already seen that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I want to accomplish is not even possible in the first place.

TABLESAMPLE cannot be used on derived tables, so it is not even feasible to have a complex query generating a large result set and then get a random sampling with TABLESAMPLE.

TABLESAMPLE is only something that can be used on the base tables that go into a query, before joins and soforth.  (see [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx))

[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx) describes a way to get a random percentage of results efficiently, so the best way to do approximately what I want may be to use that in a view, and build my LINQ off of that view.

Thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but you can use this technique to select a random percentage sample of individual rows. The following query uses the NEWID function to return approximately one percent of the rows of the Sales.SalesOrderDetail table:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail   
WHERE 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
```

Possibly of interest: [T-SQL: Generating Random Numbers, Random Sampling and Random ‘Goodness’](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2011/08/t-sql-generating-random-numbers-random.html)

Comment: Ah yes, seems similar to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx  If you have a way of doing that in a LINQ-friendly way, I am curious to know that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (syntax may not be exactly right but you should get the idea):

```
var rowCount = context.MyTable.Count();

int randomInt = new Random().Next(rowCount);    
var query = context.MyTable.Skip(randomInt).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: A couple problems I have with this approach: (1) Only gets one row per query [I want to get several rows in one shot, if possible] (2) Need to calculate the count before running my (complex!) query. I will update the question to note that the query is complex.

Answer (score 0):

With EF, you could create a defining query in your model using the tablesample construct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx. Alternatively, you could create a randomized view in your database and then include that view in your model.

Comment: TABLESAMPLE cannot be used in view definitions. There was a good comment thread about this, but the question was removed ):

Comment: (I mean the *answer* was removed :)

Comment: @jwd thanks for the correction. Defining query could still be a possibility since it is pure SQL rather than a saved view.