# Studying an Idea for extract random rows with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, random

This is actually my strategy to extract (for example) 5 random products from a list of products:

```
// extracts all products with Name Example
IList<Product> products = (from Product p in new Products()
                           where p.Name = "Example"
                           select p).ToList();

// I randomly order first 5 products
int upper = 1;
if (products.Count > 1)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    upper = Math.Min(5, products.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
    {
        int randInd = r.Next(i, products.Count);
        var temp = products[i];
        products[i] = products[randInd];
        products[randInd] = temp;
    }
}

// I get the first 5
products = products.Take(upper);
```

I have to say : I'm annoyed about extract every time all records I need with LINQ, order them and get only few.

I think there is a waste of resources of this process, such as take ALL elements with LINQ if I need only 5.

Is there a method to extract with LINQ only records at some position in the table? I mean, if I have a table of 1000 rows, get only 5 rows randomly.

This will be the same, and the use of resources will improve.

Comment: A number of approaches are shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql

Comment: Yeah, there are few methods! But no one I've requested :(

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method to extract with LINQ only records at some position
>   in the table?

The System.Linq.Queryable class provides the ElementAt(int) extension method.

Comment: Looks interessant! But it cycle the whole table if there is a where?

Comment: No, it basically does a Skip(x).Take(1), where x is your random number. But you must ensure to NOT call .ToList() as this statement loads the whole table into memory.

Comment: Uhm, that's nice! But what's about the element at Y position is not on where clause? It take the next with where clauses=true? I think this could be the faster strategy to get N random values. Just call that ElementAt N time with my values, right?

Comment: Yes: it searches only the elements covered by the query (including the where clause). So, in your case, you should call 5 times the ElementAt method (more queries against the database but much better memory usage: in 99.99%, the performance will be better too).

Comment: "more queries against the database" ? LINQ works on my `Products`, which are already "downloaded" in memory...

Comment: I thought you used LINQ to SQL. Remember, if my answer satisfies you, mark it as accepted ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a great concept to extract random 5 records from MSSQL Server by using Linq.
First create a Scalar valued function in your database like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNewId ( ) 
RETURNS uniqueidentifier 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT ID FROM RandomView) 
END
```

Please import this function in your LINQ dbml file.

Now when you are fetching records from database by using linq query at that time you will use

```
(from p in new ProductsDataContext()
orderby new ProductsDataContext().GetNewId()
select p).Take(5).ToList();
```

by using this query you get 5 random records on every call...

I think it will help you lots...