# Randomly Select Records Using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

i want to retrieve 15 records from a table of around 50 records. but i want all records to be generated randomly. if i take a random number and write something like:

```
var result = (from r in sc.Subjects
              where (r.SubName == sub && r.Level == lev)
              select r).skip(randomnumber).take(10),
```

the starting record will be random but the next 9 will be in sequence. so any idea on how i can have all 10 records random using linq to sql?

Comment: You can use the first approach in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/648247/181108).

Comment: Also check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx

Comment: Add more context, what LINQ do you use, any database?

Comment: i am using sql server express edition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to do this with a `for` loop to get the item then using `LINQ`

```
var result = new List<subject>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   randomnumber = GenerateNewRandomNumber();
   result.Add(sc.Subjects.Where(r => r.SubName == sub && r.Level == lev).Skip(randomnumber).take(1).First;

}
```

Comment: How do you know the maximum value that you can skip?

Comment: hey, your method seems to be pretty good but im getting the following error:

 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Genre>.Add(Genre)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: After the Take(1) add a `First`, right now it is Returning an IEnumberable<Genre> instead of a Genre

Comment: i am still getting the same error! searched many forums and read all about list but can't get rid of this error!

Answer (score 8):

I use this in one of my sites, to show random ads from a table. Its EF4.0, but the Linq2SQL is probably the same or similar:

```
myAds = (from q in db.Ads select q).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private static Random Generator = new Random();
...
var result = sc.Subjects.Where(s => s.SubName == sub && s.Level == lev).OrderBy(s => Generator.Next()).Take(10);
```