# Invalid cast is possible in Linq2SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, casting

I've had trouble with a Linq2SQL query. Dissection of the offending query yields this minimal example of its baffling behavior.

```
NorthwindDataContext db = 
  new NorthwindDataContext();
IEnumerable<int> q =
  from x in db.Categories
  select (int)(object)new System.Collections.ArrayList(x.CategoryID);
int[] ouch = q.ToArray();
```

(`CategoryID` is an `int`.) At the end, `ouch` will be filled with zeroes (one zero for every category in the database). I have used `int` and `ArrayList` in this example; the exact types are irrelevant. The main points needed to repeat this phenomenon are:

1. Linq2SQL. Using a local data source will produce the expected cast exception
2. Use of a property of the queried database table in the `select` expression. If no column of the queried tables is used, a cast exception will be raised.

My question is, why doesn't the above code produce an exception trying to cast the `ArrayList` into an `int`?

The generated SQL code according to LINQPad:

```
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [Categories] AS [t0]
```

As a background to my question: My original code read something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ParentClass> q =
  (from x in db.SomeTable
  select (ParentClass) new ChildClass { SomeProperty = x.SomeColumn })
  .ToArray();
```

`ChildClass` inherits from `ParentClass`. This code though correctly typed and semantically sound, raises an exception. This happens only if `db` is a Linq2SQL connection, not if it's a local data source. Trying to understand the cause of this behavior led me to the code I posted above.

Comment: is categoryID a string or an int

Comment: I don't understand why we should expect an exception here.(it might be because my lack information about casting, tough.).

Comment: I have edited the question to address your remarks.

Comment: See the edited post for the interesting SQL code

Comment: OK, so you've found an example where Linq to sql has taken a weird expression and decided to translate it in a `SELECT` list as `NULL`. What were you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cast exception occurs because the casts are sent into the database where they are performed by rules outside of .net.

It's the same reason [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648247/8155) doesn't throw.

It's the same reason that string comparison in a query is (by default) case-insensitive.

Comment: I accept this answer, because it must be the Linq2Sql query generation that changes the semantics of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
IEnumerable<int> q =
  from x in db.Categories
  select x.CategoryID;

int[] ouch = q.ToArray();
```

Comment: Please add in readable text what was wrong and what you have changed to fix the problem the original poster had. Answers that consist of only a code block are not very useful.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.