# Choose random object from list, that doesn't exist in second list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two lists:
FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist & FPTDocManagedStrategyList.

I want to be able to choose a random asset from FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist, that doesn't already exist in FPTDocManagedStrategyList to stop duplicates.

This is my code currently

```
FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist[random.Next(0, FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Count())];
```

but obviously it can include duplicated items. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you guarantee that there will always be some items in FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist that are not in FPTDocManagedStrategyList? What do you expect is the relative proportion of items that are not in the second list? The answers to these questions will determine the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method:

```
var temp = FPTStaticDataManagedStrategyAssetlist.Except(FPTDocManagedStrategyList).ToList();
if (temp.Count > 0)
{
    var item = temp[random.Next(0, temp.Count)];
}
else
{
    // no items to choose from...
}
```

You can also avoid materializing the result of `Except` to a list, by using the method posted by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql/648240#648240).

Comment: You better check that `temp.Count` isn't zero before indexing `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Filter away duplicates
var listTemp = listA.Where(i=> !listB.Contains(i)).ToList();
//Select random
var randomItem = listTemp[random.Next(0, listTemp.Count())];
```