# How to get a random nr. of items out of a repository with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a repository of objects that I'm looking at and I want to select the default 3 random items from it. I want to do this without retrieving all the items and then select the 3, I want the logic that randomizes to happen before anything else and want to do that all in one LINQ query. I'm thinking this is possible.

I'd use the query in a single method with a default parameter that signifies the number of items wanted through that query.

Comment: @Neolisk That's ordering the items of an in memory collection, not of a database.

Comment: Yes, I have to query against a database.

Comment: What library are you using? linq2sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random row from Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Entity Framework, I already solved it, but post if you have a best practice reply.